# run Django server by calling subprocess from another Django project

Tags: django, python-3.x, subprocess

I have two Django projects, `foo` and `bar`, and the structures are shown in the following.

```
/tmp/foo
  - foo
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py

/tmp/bar
  - bar
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
```

I tried to run `python3 /tmp/bar/manage.py runserver` in `foo`'s environment but failed.

```
$ python3 /tmp/foo/manage.py shell

>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['python3', '/tmp/bar/manage.py', 'runserver'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/bar/manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'foo'
1
```

How can I resolve this?

(I know this behavior doesn't make sense at all, but this is just for the demonstration purpose only.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, it doesn't make any sense at all :-) But if you really want to do that, you need to override the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'bar.settings'
>>> subprocess.call(['python3', '/tmp/bar/manage.py', 'runserver'])
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 26, 2016 - 15:52:08
Django version 1.9.6, using settings 'bar.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: Actually what I wanna do is to manipulate `bar`'s model by sending commands from `foo` (I hope this would make more sense )

Comment: It sorta kina makes sense, although IMHO it would be more convenient to send commands via an HTTP API. Have you tried the solution mentioned above? Did it work? If not, what happened?

Comment: Everything works just fine, thanks. However, is there any side-effect if I change `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']`? I still want to retain the original environment.

Comment: I don't believe there are any side effects, since the settings have already been loaded prior to running the shell.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes, could you flag it as correct? If not, what happened?